# UITablwview scroll is getting hanged

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

My app is basically a tab based one .in the first tab i have a tableview the data is loaded from a web server .my problem is that the tableview scroll is getting hanged

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462460/best-practices-fast-uitableview-scrolling), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172158/how-can-i-speed-up-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 'sendSynchronousRequest:'? Don't. Use asynchronous networking. Synchronous networking blocks the main thread, and halts UI drawing until the request returns.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is you fetch data when view gets appeared and after that you load data in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with dynamic allocation of height for tableview and also for the cell. Do a check on these. For any of your questions, make sure that you are adding some snippets of code which gives better understanding of the question.